# Showing package installation progress with WiX custom bootstrapper

Tags: c#, wpf, wix, bootstrapper

I'm currently developing a custom bootstrapper application for my WiX installer.

I currently include just a single package in my bundle to be installed and are showing the progress as following:

```
private void Bootstrapper_Progress(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
{
    ApplyingPercentage = e.ProgressPercentage;
    OverallPercentage = e.OverallPercentage;

    if (Bootstrapper.EngineModel.UserCancellationRequested)
    {
        e.Result = Result.Cancel;
    }
}
```

Now, everyone knows about the "regular" installation progress the windows installer gives to the user.

What I want to do is to give the user the same amount of progress in my custom bootstrapper application, which unfortunately only shows a tiny amount (0% - 50% - 100%).

I assume it only shows the progress of installed packages within the bundle and not the progress of the actual package itself (which the Windows Installer shows on default, because only one package is going to get installed).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnCacheAcquireProgress`'s `OverallPercentage` provides more granular cache progress and `OnExecuteProgress`'s `OverallPercentage` provides more granular execution progress.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find any official documentation about the bootstrapper events unfortunately.